# A Solution to the Friedmann Equation

Tags: cosmology, curvature

In cosmology I have seen three kinds of energy densities: that of matter, radiation, and dark energy. I have seen solutions to the First Friedmann equation when the universe contains either one of these + curvature. Energy densities have an equational form: $\rho = \rho_0 a^{-3(1 + \omega)}$, where matter has $\omega = 0$, radiation has $\omega = 1/3$ and dark energy $\omega = -1$. Suppose there was a new kind of energy density with $-1/5 < \omega < 1$ with $\omega \neq 0$ and consider an universe with only this energy and curvature $\kappa$. The first Friedmann equation is: $\dot{a}^2 = \frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}a^2 - \kappa = \frac{8\pi G\rho_0a^{-3(1+\omega)}}{3} - \kappa = \beta a^{-3(1+\omega)} - \kappa$. From this I got the following integral equation

$\int_0^{a}da\sqrt{\frac{a^{3\omega + 1}}{\beta - a^{3\omega + 1}\kappa}} = \pm\int_{0}^{t}dt$. When $\kappa = 0$, I can solve this equation as $a(t) = (\pm 1.5(\omega + 1)t)^{1/(3\omega + 3)}$ and so I have an expanding universe. However when the universe is curved, I am unable to determine the scale factor as a function of time. Can anyone tell me how I might try to solve this problem I created? Will such a universe expand or collapse? Is there an easier way I can approximate $a(t)$ if this cannot be solved exactly? Please let me know?

Comment: This is a math question about whether a particular integral can be done analytically.

Comment: You left out the $da$.

Comment: $\omega = +1/3$ for radiation

Comment: *Is there an easier way I can approximate () if this cannot be solved exactly?* Any integral can be evaluated numerically.

Comment: fixed changed you pointed out

Comment: This integral is expressible in terms of the hypergeometric function. Use Wolfram|Alpha or Mathematica